# Fetching only duplicates from a csv file

Tags: unix

Could you please help in fetching duplicates from a specific column in a csv file in unix.
Tried with uniq utility, it works only with txt file.
Please suggest.

Comment: Hey @yatheendra , this is a very broad question and is off topic , please see the link to know more on how best to put forward your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is it in excel format? Can you execute `$ file your_file_name.csv` command and see what it says?

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting the value before applying uniq.

```
awk -F ',' '{print $1}' <filenname> |sort | uniq
```